# TCL/TK windows black in ZOOM "share portion of screen"

Tags: tk-toolkit, zoom-sdk

I have a weird effect in ZOOM which only appears for TCL/TK windows.

Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME window manager. ZOOM version 5.10.3 (2778) (relatively new, I was forced to do an update, the problem is also new). TCL/TK 8.6.

1. I start a ZOOM session and share a "portion of screen" (Share - Advanced).
2. I run `wish` from the command line. I move the `wish` window into the shared screen portion.
3. For the client users of the ZOOM session, the `wish` window is visible if it has the focus.
4. When I move the focus to another window, e.g. a terminal, outside the shared screen portion, the clients only see a black region somewhat larger than the `wish` window (instead of the `wish` window).
5. When I move the focus to a window, e.g. a terminal, which is at least partly inside the shared screen portion, the `wish` window stays visible.
6. If I share the entire screen in ZOOM (which is not what I want for my purposes, though), the `wish` window stays visible.

This is so weird, I don't even have the slightest idea what is going on. What is special about TCL/TK windows that they go black in ZOOM, but only under these circumstances?

Comment: Are you running X or Wayland?

Comment: @slebetman: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` says `x11`.

Comment: I just noticed that the problem disappears if also the ZOOM client is updated (now I'm at ZOOM 5.10.4 for both the zoom session and the zoom client, running on different machines). But still: what's so special about TK windows?

Comment: Tk was implemented at a very low level not on top of more popular toolkits like GTK or Qt. I was wondering if there were any incompatibilities with newer display managers like Wayland. But if you are using X11 then it's a bit weird since Tk has been stable since the 1980s

Comment: Sounds like it's some sort of unexpected event pattern that Tk is ignoring (and the ignoring of that is something which Zoom interprets as "go black"). Very odd, and possibly a Zoom bug (given that updating the Zoom client fixed it, and they encourage keeping up to date). Alas, given that a newer version of Zoom fixes it, there's not much anyone's going to be able to do to hunt this down. Even if it was more easily reproducible, it'd *still* be very difficult to trace. (Event handling bugs always are horrible; there's just so many events behind the scenes!)

Comment: Also, the above is a Wild Assed Guess. I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still there. I'm not sure why it had seemed to disappear after an update of the ZOOM client, but another test showed that it persists.